# Azure B2C - Losing Authentication context after forgot password/ reset

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have an existing / relatively new Azure B2C implementation that I'm just starting to jump into. The process to signup and log in has been running great. The forgotten password functionality is sending off a verification code correctly, and changing the password as expected. But it seems to lose authentication context afterwards when sending you back to the app, which inevitably just crashes - regardless of the app I've tested with.

Any insight on troubleshooting would be appreciated!

Comment: More details would be helpful. Are you using a user flow or a custom policy?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure have [Application Insights logging enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) if you are using a custom policy. Even if you are just using a user flow, check Application Insights for the activity related to your sign in.

Also, enable logging with your application to confirm receipt of the claims.

You can also inspect HTTP traffic with a tool like Fiddler to confirm that the requests & responses are successful as expected.